# SQLl Like is not working string contain single quotes in php mysql

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-like, single-quotes

SQL LIKE is not working when string contains single quote `'`,
Below is my **php code**

```
  $keysearch = "St.Joseph's"; // Searching keyword containing single quotes
  $sql =mysqli_query("select id,name from tbl where name LIKE '%$keysearch%'");
```

It returns no result,
How can I search a string contain single quotes?
Is there any effective operator except 'LIKE' for comparing single quotes value in DB?

Comment: Learn aboup prepared statements

Comment: Use prepared statements and you'll never have to worry about pesky quoting issues ever again.

Comment: Use prepared statements or escape the characters. If you plan to do the search through user input, your code is deemed to fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `addslashes()` function of PHP as below,

```
$sql =mysqli_query($con,"select id,name from tbl where name LIKE '%".addslashes($keysearch)."%'");
```